# Layout para barra de botões no estilo Material

Tags: android-layout

Estou tentando criar uma barra de botões na parte inferior da tela (botões "Cancelar" e "Salvar" semelhante à usada pelo Google Drive:
[image: GDrive]

Porém, em nenhum lugar dos guidelines do Material eu encontrei algo referente à essa barra. Não existe especificação de altura, margens, etc. O mais próximo que encontrei foi [isso](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html), mas no entanto esse link não abrange barras fixas na parte inferior da tela.

Até o momento, estou com esse resultado:
[image: Meu app]

Porém, parece simplesmente errado. Não aparenta ter a mesma altura, o posicionamento dos botões é diferente e eu ainda não consegui colocar a linha divisória na parte de cima. Esse é o meu XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.renanlazarotto.fserv2.activities.NovoChamadoActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/chamados_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ciano_500"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/novo_scroll"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chamados_toolbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/novo_botoes"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    ...
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/novo_botoes"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="@string/novo_botao_cancelar"
        android:id="@+id/novo_botao_cancelar"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"  />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="@string/novo_botao_abrir"
        android:id="@+id/novo_botao_abrir"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ciano_500" />
</LinearLayout>
```

O item em questão é o último LinearLayout. Como posso melhorar esse layout para que ele se pareça mais com a imagem do Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a barra a que se refere é a área de ação de um **Dialog**. Acredito até que essa tela do *Google Drive* é um *Dialog* em *Full Screen*.

Para *Dialog*  em *FullScreen* eles dão uma outra disposição das ações, mas essa forma do *Google Drive* não contraria os Guidelines.

O link para *Dialogs* em *Fullscreen* é http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-confirmation-dialogs (seção de **Full-screen dialogs**)

As métricas para essa área de botões de ação é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais detalhes em: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs

Referências:

- http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html

Comment: Não tinha visto aquela janela como um diálogo, na verdade sequer se passou em minha mente essa possibilidade. As métricas dos botões já estou usando, vou aplicar as métricas de um diálogo de tela cheia, acredito que vá ficar até mais bonito do que o diálogo do Google Drive. Obrigado pela informação!